# scp - transfer reports 100% complete (and is transferred), but file size is incorrect

Tags: linux, expect, scp

I am using scp to transfer files between two linux systems - when the transfer finishes, the final print to screen from SCP shows the wrong file size:

```
vmtbackup.zip                                       100% 2613MB  17.5MB/s   02:29 .
```

As you can see here, the final reported size is 2613MB and the transfer has completed. However the actual size of the file is 2741MB

When I check on the target system, the file has the correct size (so the transfer has completed successfully).

I am using the output from SCP as part of a script, and the check condition to finish the script is when the size in SCP = the size of the file (as the 100% is equally unreliable) - it's part of an expect script, which looks like this:

```
function Transfer {
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
#transfers the vmtbackup.zip file from source system to target system

spawn scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /tmp/vmtbackup.zip $user@$ip:/tmp/
expect {
#handles all unexpected outcomes. Primarily used to capture wrong 

password, as no remote connection should be caught earlier in migration.sh
default { 
send_user "\nERROR: I was unable to connect to $ip for some reason.  Please try again.\n"
exit 1
}
#passes the password defined in migration.sh to scp password prompt"
-re "root@$ip's \[pP\]assword:" {
send -- "$password\r"
exp_continue
}
-re "\[pP\]assword:" {
send -- "$password\r"
exp_continue
}
-re "ETA" {
exp_continue
}
#when file transfer reaches 100%, exits script
-re "$si" {
exit 0
}
EOD
}
```

I'm aware of the security implications of using password in plaintext and that I should use SSL, but for now that's not part of the problem.

Can anyone tell me why SCP behaves in this way?

Answer (score 2):

`scp` incorrectly shows `MB`, which means the factor is `1000 * 1000`. It should show `MiB`, which is factor `1024 * 1024`:

```
2613 MiB == 2613 * (1024 * 1024) / (1000 * 1000) == 2739.929088 MB
```

See [IEEE 1541-2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1541-2002) for details.

Comment: Filled a bug for OpenSSH: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2701

Comment: @Jakuje They might reply that `scp` predates IEEE 1541-2002 and changing the output units may break existing applications. It may make sense to add a new command line option `--si-units` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, but the same code is used in the SFTP, which is "quite modern" and has the same issue. Also we need to move forward somehow. And better keep it tracked than sorry.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks very much! This is exactly what it is. I grab the size of the file using ls -l --block-size=MB /tmp | grep -i vmtbackup.zip | awk '{ print $5 }' so I will just change it to ls -l --block-size=M /tmp | grep -i vmtbackup.zip | awk '{ print $5 }' and that should fix my problem?

Comment: I would mention though that there is a discrepancy of about 0.04 percent between MiB and MB which on larger files can still potentially cause an issue on my side (SCP reports 2613 MiB, ls reports 2614MiB) but it's closer to the solution!

Comment: @user3074653 Can be a rounding issue, since the fraction is not displayed.

Comment: @Maxim Is there anyway to make the size more specific?

Comment: @user3074653 Another way is to obtain the list of copied files (may be -v scp option) and then stat the files for file sizes.